# Custom fields not showing up in the user info (PaidMembershipsPro)

Tags: plugins, php, membership, plugin-members

I have added a custom field into the registration for in pmpro (https://gist.github.com/travislima/391c0db4121366a40eaa1bb5f8d18978), and now I am trying to retrieve that data using php. The problem is that not only I could not find a way of getting user info from php (except for the membership level), but also in the member profile this field is shown as empty. What can I do to get this data?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was redirecting users to the main page after registration, which apparently messes with PMPro, so I just removed that.